# Method returning a string of Arrays with integer and string as parameters

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I am trying to use a method that accepts an integer and then a string and returns a string array. The string is split using a comma delimiter. Each element of the array is supposed to be defaulted to empty before storing the data split by the delimiter.

My question is what would I put into the for loop to receive that output? or is the for loop even necessary.

This is what I have so far:

```java
public static String[] parseString(int arraySize, String input) {
    String[] array = input.split(", ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

    }
    return array;
}
```

This is an example of how it is called in the main:

```java
String[] result;
result = Utility.parseString(3, "apple, pear, peach, plum, kiwi");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ". [" + result[i] + "]");
}
```

and this is an example of the correct output:

```
0. [apple]
1. [pear]
2. [peach]
```

Compared to my output right now.

```
0. [apple]
1. [pear]
2. [peach]
3. [plum]
4. [kiwi]
```

Comment: What is your question? Please be specific and clear as much as possible

Comment: edited the post with more information.

Comment: Try this: ```String array[] = input.split(",") ; String newArray = new String[arraySize] ;  for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
 newArray[i] = array[i];  } return newArray``` I also recommend to check the array size, to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: You don't need an int arraySize because the size is determined solely by the String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the array to have `arraySize` elements. `split` will give you an array with just the right number of elements, or fewer/more elements than you need. You can handle each of these cases separately. In the latter case, you use a for loop to copy the elements in `array` to a new array with length `arraySize`.

```
String[] array = input.split(", ");
if (array.length == arraySize) {
    return array;
} else {
    String[] newArray = new String[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++) {
        if (i < array.length) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        } else { // this will be reached if split gave us fewer elements than we need
            newArray[i] = "";
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the helpful methods in `Arrays`:

```
String[] array = input.split(", ");
if (array.length == arraySize) {
    return array;
} else if (array.length < arraySize) { // split gave us fewer elements than we need
    // this produces a copy of the array, with extra nulls at the end of the array
    String[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, arraySize);
    // so we fill those nulls with ""
    Arrays.fill(newArray, array.length, arraySize, "");
    return newArray;
} else { // split gave us more elements than we need, copyOf will do exactly what we want
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, arraySize);
}
```

Comment: the first option got it for me thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your method **parseString** must be like this:

```
public static String[] parseString(int arraySize, String input)
{
String[] array = new String[arraySize]
String [] aux =  input.split(", ");

for(int i=0;i<arraySize; i++)
{
    array[i] = aux[i];
}
return array;

}
```

But, you must be careful, because the code **input.split(", ")** can return a length which can cause en ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

I mean that when you try to access to **aux[i]** can be possible that the i value it's is greater or equal than **aux.length**

Comment: so if the array size is longer than the input, how would I keep from getting that error?

Comment: so say the method is called and it is parseString(3, "pear") how do you keep from getting an error there

Comment: With a simple if, for example the code 
result = Utility.parseString(3, "apple");
The input "apple" when you try to split by ","  will return an array of size 1, and its unique element will be "apple"
So, in your method "parseString"  you can type the next code:
String [] aux =  input.split(", ");
if (aux.length < arraySize) {
  return null; //or you can return the array or throw an Excpetion
}
The statement inside the if maybe what you want

Comment: The another answer it's good! You should check it
It has the necessary for validations and avoiding some Exception

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of ***Java Streams***, you could make your code simpler,
less error-prone and more self-explanatory.

Try this, please:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result = parseString(3, "apple, pear, peach, plum, kiwi", ",");
        IntStream.range(0, result.size())
                .forEach(idx -> System.out.println(idx + ". [" + result.get(idx) + "]"));
    }

    private static List<String> parseString(int arraySize, String input, String delimiter) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split(delimiter))
                .map(String::trim)
                .limit(arraySize)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

#### Resources

**Java Streams**

- stream()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html
- limit()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-
- collect()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-
- forEach()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-
- IntStream
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html
- intstream.range()
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you it is for the beginning of my data structures class so I'm not that experienced to work with javastream yet, but will have to read into it.

Comment: @tristanhoward, okay. Take your time, please. We were all beginners at one point in time. I just wanted to let you know about other improved alternatives.